# Unable to extend Django 2.1 password reset template

Tags: django

I'm trying to extend the password reset form like so:

```
<!-- templates/registration/password_reset_form.html -->
{% extends registration/password_reset_form.html %}

{% block content %}
<h1> hello </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

As far as I can tell, this should take the template from `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_template.html` (which exists, I checked) and replace the `block content` with the one at `templates/registration/password_reset_form.html`.

But this isn't happening. In fact, there is no change, nor is there an error. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I tried deliberately introducing a syntax error into the template name, and no error was issued. It leads me to believe that the template file is not being read at all. According to the django docs, `registration/password_reset_form.html` is the path to the default template. Why am I not able to at least introduce an error?

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around path, like this:

```
{% extends "registration/password_reset_form.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1> hello </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Also if your own template file didn't read at all, make sure that you have your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` and `TEMPLATES` has `'APP_DIRS': True` or `DIRS` set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the full path to the html file then?
`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_template.html`

Right now you are extending the same file you are working on

Comment: i'd rather not use an absolute path as it will change depending on the environment. do you know of any way i can do this with a relative path? the django docs use the relative path i've written above.

Comment: Try changing the name of your file. I think you are overriding the path to the default django template

Comment: does not work. please see edits, even deliberately introducing an error does not work.